# Using a matrix or array in Swift to determine an outcome based on two input variables

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

I'm new to swift and working on developing my first app in Xcode. I'm trying to create a global set of functions that I can call throughout all View Controllers. However, I can't seem to get my function to work properly. I have tried using Array, Dictionary, and a matrix. Essentially, there are two players and each player has 5 choices. I want the function to take the players' choices and run those choices through the matrix to determine the win-result (e.g., Player 1 Wins!). I then want this result to be sent to a label. It's not in the code below, but I am using results.text for the label. I got this to work in "if / else" format, but would really like it to be cleaned up to something similar to the code below instead.

The latest code is below, and the errors I get now are:

1. Cannot convert return expression of type 'Array<[String]>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Array>') to return type 'String''
2. Extra argument in call
3. Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'MPSingleViewController.Choice' conform to 'RangeExpression'

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol RangeExpression {} // Don't know if I need this....

class MPSingleViewController: UIViewController {

// other code here //

enum Choice: String {
    case apple = "apple"
    case banana = "banana"
    case cone = "cone"
    case date = "date"
    case elf = "elf"}

var varibles: [String: Int] =
    
[ "apple": 0, "banana": 1, "cone": 2, "date": 3, "elf": 4 ]


func outcome (player1: Choice, player2: Choice) ->  String  {
                 
    let Axx = [ 
        ["Draw", "Win", "Lose", "Lose", "Win"],
        ["Lose", "Draw", "Win", "Win", "Lose"],
        ["Win", "Lose", "Draw", "Lose", "Win"],
        ["Win", "Lose", "Win", "Draw", "Lose"],
        ["Lose", "Win", "Lose", "Win", "Draw"]
    ]
    
   return Axx[player1, player2]
    
    }

   // Other code here // }
```

Comment: You are mixing types and using variables here in such a confusing manner it's hard to understand what the code should do. Is `varibles` really a variable or a constant? Why not make the associated value of your enum an Int instead of a String and if you want to access a 2d array you do it like `Axx[1][2]`. For instance if your enum was declared `enum Choice: Int` then you could do something like `Axx[player1.rawValue][player2.rawValue]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need of `variables` and use `Int` as the *RawType* of `enum Choice`, i.e.

```
enum Choice: Int {
    case apple, banana, cone, date, elf
}
```

Now, simply return **`Axx[player1.rawValue][player2.rawValue]`** from the method `outcome(player1:player2:)`,

```
let Axx = [
    ["Draw", "Win", "Lose", "Lose", "Win"],
    ["Lose", "Draw", "Win", "Win", "Lose"],
    ["Win", "Lose", "Draw", "Lose", "Win"],
    ["Win", "Lose", "Win", "Draw", "Lose"],
    ["Lose", "Win", "Lose", "Win", "Draw"]
]

func outcome (player1: Choice, player2: Choice) ->  String  {
    return Axx[player1.rawValue][player2.rawValue]
}
```

You can move `Array` `Axx` out of the method `outcome(player1:player2:)`.